# jQuery Mobile ListView with Gradients as Custom Background

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to style my  listview with custom gradients as backgrounds (gradients generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/  )

I would like each

contain different gradient as background from colorzilla + I would like to double the height of each

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/flymen8888/zgNJy/

Thank you so much for your help! Best

```
<!-- Start of index page -->
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li><a href="#">PAGE A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PAGE B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PAGE C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PAGE D</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
    <!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /index page -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add style to *anchors* within *listview*.

```
.ui-listview a {
  height: 60px;
  background: red; /* or gradient */
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4zVgY/)**